# Is there anyway to take the snapshot and drift of a WAS ND 7/8/liberty an WLS instance(s) through WAS Admin commands or Jython scripts

Tags: websphere, weblogic

Is there anyway to take the snapshot and drift of a WAS ND 7/8/liberty and Weblogic instance(s) through WAS/WLS Admin commands or Jython scripts? A Snapshot here means complete information, not only topology but the whole details(like cell, node, jvms/servers, jdbc, jms, shared lib etc configurations) in a single XML file or any other format and a drift will be the difference between two Snapshot in report.

Answer (score 0):

For WAS ND 8.5.5 you could use [Extended Repository Service](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twve_xdappedcfg.html?lang=en), it is available via console or scripting. It allows you to:

- Create full or delta checkpoint
- Archive checkpoints to save product configurations
- Delete checkpoints to free up disk space and remove unwanted checkpoints.
- Restore checkpoints.
- Find configuration changes in delta checkpoints.

it is not a single xml file, but maybe will fulfill your requirements. See that page for more details.

For WAS 7 you could export your configuration via Property Based Configuration - [Extracting properties files using wsadmin scripting](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/txml_7extractprops.html?lang=en). Exported file is a text, properties file with configuration details.

WebSphere Liberty has just  one configuration file - `server.xml`, so save it and compare with later files. The other files which might be customized are `server.env`, `bootstrap.properties`, `jvm.options`, so you should also compare them to not miss any custom settings.

Answer (score 0):

For WebLogic, the pack command provides a simple way to snapshot a whole domain. The result is a .jar file with many files, but at least you could run a file level compare.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e14144/intro.htm#WLDPU161